# MongoMapper "keys must be strings or symbols" with OR query

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

I have this query :

```
Model.where({'$or' => [{:date => nil}, {:date.gt => Time.new}]}).count
```

I get an error :

```
keys must be strings or symbols
```

I split the or query in two, and both works. May I make a mistake for $or ?

Just in case : mongo mapper 0.9.2 ;)

And just in case, I update to 0.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But it works this way :

```
.where({:$or => [{:date => nil}, {:date => {:$gt => nil}}]})
```

I don't know why.

How did I found ? Miss enter on this

```
.where({:$or => [{:date => nil}]})
```

Funny right ?

Comment: `:date.gt` is not a Symbol, it is a SymbolOperator.

Comment: but .where(:data.gt => Time.new) works and it's also a SymbolOperator. It means that SymbolOperator auto replacement logic break in nested queries ? :s

Comment: But `where(:data.gt => Time.now)` doesn't use `:$or`. I'm not certain what's going on behind the scenes here, seems like a strange restriction in any case.

Comment: Yah, plucky needs to support symbol operators in `:$or` clauses, but it doesn't. I [opened an issue](https://github.com/jnunemaker/plucky/issues/12) a while back but no-one (included myself) has fixed it yet.

Comment: See [this pull request](https://github.com/jnunemaker/plucky/pull/20). Hopefully it'll be in plucky 0.4.5.